# If $Α$ is a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ then $f(x)=\sup\{|x-a|: a\in A\}, \ x\in A$ is uniformly continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

I am trying to solve this exercise, but it is hard to understand it.

If $Α$ is a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ then $f(x)=\sup\{|x-a|: a\in A\}, \ x\in A$  is uniformly continuous function. Please help me, I am stuck. Thanks

Comment: This question has been ask many times, just use the search function :) the function will even turn out to be lipschitz.

Comment: Prove that $f(x) \leq f(y)+|x-y|$ ( and  $f(y) \leq f(x)+|x-y|$).

Comment: Ok Thanks. I proved it. It's useful to know that for every B subset of $\mathbb{R}$ it holds $sup(b+B)=b+supB$